# Google Map fitBound not ZOOM in for first time for ployline

Tags: javascript, google-maps

i am using fitbound function to autozooom on polyline of map. but on first time it not works properly if  i change the chartData and call same function again it works fine. the function code is below.

```
var mapOptions = {
                    zoom: 1,
                    center: { lat: 0, lng: 0 },
                    zoomControl: true,
                    zoomControlOptions: {
                        style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL
                    },
                    mapTypeId: 'satellite'
                };
                this.chart = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(chart_element.id), mapOptions);
                let polylinePath = new google.maps.Polyline({
                    path: chart_data,
                    geodesic: true,
                    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
                    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
                    strokeWeight: 2
                });

                /* set auto zoom level to polyline */

                var latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
                for (var i = 0; i < this.chartData.length; i++) {
                    latlngbounds.extend(this.chartData[i]);
                }

                this.chart.fitBounds(latlngbounds);

                /* Set polyline chart to map */
                polylinePath.setMap(this.chart);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
// Set zoom level
var boundsListener = google.maps.event.addListener((map), 'bounds_changed', function(event) {
    this.setZoom(11);
    google.maps.event.removeListener(boundsListener);
});
```

Comment: we can not set fixed zoom, because some time the polyline in large area at that time it will show more zoom in then expected.

Answer (score 1):

you can add one prototype method `getBounds()` to `google.maps.Polyline`:
and then scale the `Map` according to the `Polyline`'s `LatLngBounds`, by first setting the map and then fitting to bounds.

```
polyline.setMap(map);
map.fitBounds(polyline.getBounds());
```

also, the *path* in your code is once called `chart_data`, and then `this.chartData` ...

```js
var map;
var timeout;
var coordinates = [
  {lat: 37.772, lng: -122.214},
  {lat: 21.291, lng: -157.821},
  {lat: -18.142, lng: 178.431},
  {lat: -27.467, lng: 153.027}
];

var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
  path: coordinates,
  geodesic: true,
  strokeColor: '#FFD034',
  strokeOpacity: 1.0,
  strokeWeight: 2
});

var mapOptions = {
  mapTypeId: 'satellite',
  zoom: 20,
  zoomControl: true,
  zoomControlOptions: {
    style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL
  }
};

google.maps.Polyline.prototype.getBounds = function() {
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  this.getPath().forEach(function(e) {bounds.extend(e);});
  return bounds;
};

function onLoad() {

  /* creating the map and plotting the polyline */
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);  
  polyline.setMap(map);
  
  /* initially fitting the map to bounds */
  map.fitBounds(polyline.getBounds());
  
  /* subsequent events, which fit the map to bounds (may prevent manual zoom). */
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed',
    function() {
      window.clearTimeout(timeout);
      timeout = window.setTimeout(function () {
        map.fitBounds(polyline.getBounds());
      }, 500);
    }
  );
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", onLoad);
```

```css
html, body, #map_canvas {height: 100%; width: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Comment: i am not getting any error but the things are same before implementing this and after

Comment: {b: {b: 73.78259920000005, f: 73.78261109999994}, f: {b: 18.5627059, f: 18.5627221}}

Comment: @Robingupta just hit "Run code snippet" above; it works, even when embedded into here; also in full-screen: https://nvd3.syslogic.io/maps.html
please accept the answer, because it just works.